# Angular firebase can not connect to AngularFireDatabase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to connect to Firebase real-time database but I get an error

```
@firebase/database: FIREBASE FATAL ERROR: Cannot parse Firebase url. Please use https://<YOUR FIREBASE>.firebaseio.com

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: FIREBASE FATAL ERROR: Cannot parse Firebase url. Please use https://<YOUR FIREBASE>.firebaseio.com 
Error: FIREBASE FATAL ERROR: Cannot parse Firebase url. Please use https://<YOUR FIREBASE>.firebaseio.com
```

and in my app.module.ts I have these modules

```
AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig ),
AngularFireDatabaseModule
```

In my service I have this code

```
  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {  }
  
  getCustomersList() {
    return this.db.list('students').snapshotChanges()
  }
```

When I changed url and now it's ended with firebaseio.com I got warn

```
@firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: Namespace studenci-firebase-default-rtdb lives in a different region. Please change your database URL to
```

and when I changed url to this suggested by a warning I got the first error from this question.

Any idea why it's not working?

Comment: Did you copy and paste your config values from your firebase console?

Comment: @dshukertjr Yes I did

Comment: This issue is kind of hard without actually seeing your configuration. Is there a chance you can paste the configuration here? You could always recreate a project to dump the config values you expose here.